# Not able to push to Kafka and even call backs doesnt get executed

Tags: spring-boot, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have requirement to push the request and response of my microservice to a Kafka broker.

I am able to do it successfully with a locally setup Kafka.But when i take it to the higher environment, it fails with the below error.

```
o.a.k.clients.producer.KafkaProducer: [Producer clientId=producer-9]
Closing the Kafka producer with
timeoutMillis = 0 ms.",
"source":"stdout",
"tag":"PromiseEngine-Staging-aafa49a1ea22"}
```

I havent set the timeout to zero and i could see in the producer configs timeout is 30000 ms.

Also i have implemented success and failure callbacks,and none of them is getting executed.

```java
@Autowired
    KafkaTemplate<String, KafkaMessageDTO> kafkaTemplate;

private void publishToKafkaTopic(String topic,
        SchedulingCallRequestDTO request, ScheduleOrderResponseDTOv2 response) {
    log.debug("entered publishToKafkaTopic: " + CommonUtils.getJson(response));
    ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, KafkaMessageDTO>> future =
        send(topic,new KafkaMessageDTO(request, response));
    future.addCallback(
            new ListenableFutureCallback<SendResult<String, KafkaMessageDTO>>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(SendResult<String, KafkaMessageDTO> result) {
            log.info("Eequest and Response pushed to Kafka: " +
                CommonUtils.getJson(result.getProducerRecord().value()));
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Throwable ex) {
            log.error("Error occured while pushing to Kafka." + " {}",
                CommonUtils.getJson(new KafkaMessageDTO(request, response)));
        }
    });
}


private ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, KafkaMessageDTO>> send(String topic, KafkaMessageDTO message) {
        log.debug("entered send: " + CommonUtils.getJson(message));

        ListenableFuture<SendResult<String, KafkaMessageDTO>> future = kafkaTemplate
                .send(generateProducerRecord(topic, message));

        return future;
    }
```

Can someone help me with this

Comment: Can you add code for kafka producer send method,

Comment: I have added the send method code.I am not creating a Kafka producer.I just supply the boot strap server , serializer and deserializer to the producer inside the Kafkatemplate through my properties file . @asolanki